# Queries reasonable usage and storage with R and Hadoop

Tags: sql, r, hadoop, impala

I'm working on anomaly detection with timeseries using R. The data is stored in Hadoop. There is a sequence of queries to execute during the script runs and they are quite different.

I wanted to know what is the best way to stock these queries to easily maintain in case of changes in tables structure or access path? For example, I've seen that using Impala or Hive I can save queries, but could I then call them from R with RJDBC package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess even dynamic queries with table structure and access path dependencies; created using `paste()` and stored like function `getQuery1()` could help you. Just have them saved in your edge node.

Comment: could you please explain more in detail or give a link with an example?